# Java Producing Error when Turning String to Int

Tags: java

When converting a `String` to an `int` using the following code, I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null1"
```

Here is the code (well, the line the error occurs):

```
int numbProgram=
  Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(standardProgramResult) - output[0])
  + Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(standardProgramResult) - output[1])
  + Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(standardProgramResult) - output[2])
  + Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(standardProgramResult) - output[3])
  + Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(standardProgramResult) - output[4])
  + Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(standardProgramResult) - output[5])
  + Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(standardProgramResult) - output[6])
  + Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(standardProgramResult) - output[7]);
```

So what does `null1` mean? Shouldn't that just mean 1 because null means nothing? And also, how can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is `null1` and not `null`? Anyway to get better help post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and entire stacktrace.

Comment: What is the value of `standardProgramResult`? And why are you calling `parseInt()` so many times? Do you know what a for loop is?

Comment: standardProgramResult is probably not a proper int - so it throws an error while trying to parse it.

Comment: Please include the code that defines `standardProgramResult`.

Comment: Then it means that `standardProgramResult` is `"null1"` which is not proper integer and it can't be parsed to `int` so you are getting `NumberFormatException`. If you ware expecting `standardProgramResult` to have other value than `null1` then problem lies in code which you are not showing us so we can't help you much. For now it looks like it was result of concatenating `null` with numeric String (in this case `"1"`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you can parse only one time and use a loop:

```
int programResult = Integer.parseInt(standardProgramResult);
int numbProgram=0;
for (int output: output){
  numProgram += Math.abs(programResult - output)
}
```

That said, `standardProgramResult` does not contain an integer value and can not be parsed. The exception is showing that.

Somewhere in your code you **probably** have something like:

```
standardProgramResult = someVar1 + someVar2;
```

And `someVar1` is `"null"`.

To better understand and handle this use exceptions:

```
int programResult = 0;
try {
    programResult = Integer.parseInt(standardProgramResult);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.err.println("programResult was not a number: " + programResult);
    // possibly ignore error, or terminate...
    // e.printStackTrace(); // prints the stack trace
    // throw e; // throws the error for someone else to handle
    // System.exit(1); // terminate indicating an error in execution
}
int numbProgram=0;
for (int output: output){
    numProgram += Math.abs(programResult - output)
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, the for loop can be written as `for (int output: output)`. I'm not sure which is better, though...

Comment: Oh, found my problem. I was starting a new process and the standard output for that was null. I realized that because you said that I added up to variables in it and one of them was null. Thanks

Comment: @APCoding glad to help, you should add exception handling, you may want to ignore the error, or terminate in a more polite way :)

Comment: Your try-catch example is broken; the message in the `NumberFormatException` already contains the unparsed text, and furthermore `Math.abs()` doesn't raise a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: @dimo414 ahh thanks, I mean well... I gave an example, he may not want to print the error at all.

Comment: There's still no point to your try-catch, the message in the exception already contains the information you're printing.  And you want `standardProgramResult`, not `programResult`.

Comment: @dimo414 I left one option and commented-out popular alternatives.

Comment: @APCoding I suggest you learn how to use a debugger. It is a great tool that will help you track down these kinds of errors.

Comment: How are any of those better than just failing?  `throw e;` in particular is silly, that's identical to just not catching in the first place. This a programming logic error which correctly triggered a `RuntimeException`.  If you didn't expect to cause the exception, you should let it propagate.

Comment: It's not "silly" if you want to log the error first (or do anything actually), and then throw it in case someone else can handle it. These are actual examples I've seen in different situations.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `standardProgramResult` is `null`. You need to use a debugger to find out why.

I have two suggestions which don't directly answer your question, but will help you figure out what the problem is:

1. Assign the value of `parseInt()` to a variable so you can reuse the result as many times as you wish:

   ```
   int result = Integer.parseInt(standardProgramResult);
   ```

   In general, you shouldn't do too much in a single line of code as it makes it more difficult to track down errors.
2. Use a for loop whenver you have an array of values and need to repeat the same task for each value in the array.

Comment: `standardProgramResult` is not `null`, it would raise a `NullPointerException` if it were.  It is the string `"null1"`.

Comment: @dimo414 The [documentation for `parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) mentions nothing about throwing an NPE. I'm certain that I have seen it throw a `NumberFormatException` for `null` input, which would certainly conform to the documented behavior. Assuming that the `"null1"` isn't a typo, you are probably correct that the `String` isn't actually `null`.

Comment: Yes, apparently it [raises a `NumberFormatException` for `null`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/f097ca2434b1/src/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#l444).  Nevertheless, `"null1"` is clearly not a typo, the error message for `null` is simply `"null"`.

Comment: @dimo414 Thus the possibility of a typo by accidentally adding an extraneous `1`.

Comment: No.  The message in OP's post is `For input string: "null1"`.  This is clearly different from `null`.